# Recursive definition of predecessor vertices in a graph

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, recursion

In an directed acyclic graph $G = (V,E)$, how can I define a set $P_v \in V$ that includes a given vertex $v$ and all its direct and indirect predecessors?

I would define the direct predecessors $P^d_v = \{u \mid (u,v) \in E\} \cup \{v\}$, but I can't work out how to define it in this way to include all of the indirect predecessors as well (i.e., all predecessors of $u$ and then all predecessors of those predecessors of $u$, etc). My intuition is that I would have to use some sort of recursive definition, and I can write an algorithm for it, but I can't work out how to write it using set-builder notation.

EDIT:

Can I say something like this?

Starting with $P_v = \{v\}$, the set of predecessors can be constructed recursively in the following way:

$P_v = P_v \cup \{ b \mid (b,a) \in E, \forall a \in P_v\}$

does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_v$ can be defined as the intersection of all "pred-closed" sets that contain $v$ where I call a set $A \subseteq V$ pred-closed, iff

$$\forall x \in A: (y,x) \in E \to y \in A\tag{p}$$ i.e. a set closed under the predecessor relationship.

So a simple lemma shows that any intersection of pred-closed sets is pred-closed.

And $V$ itself is trivially pred-closed.

So $P_v= \bigcap\{A \subseteq V: A \text{ pred-closed and } v \in A\}$ is well-defined and is pred-closed (and minimally so).

This is a common idea to avoid recursion (although there is nothing wrong with recursion per se, and it also doesn't imply an "algorithm" requirement...) and IMHO quite elegant. You can show that Elliot's set gives the same set in a DAG.

Comment: Ah thanks, i like this answer. Just so that I am 100% sure on how it works, we are taking all subsets of $V$ that contain $v$, finding their pred-closed sets and then taking the intersection of all of those sets to find $P_v$?

Comment: @guskenny83 No, you take all subsets that are pred-closed and contain $v$. It's a typical external vs internal definition question.

Comment: ah yes, i see now.. I was just trying to work out why it was taking the intersection and not the union, but obviously, if $V$ is pred-closed and contains $v$, then the union would just be $V$, i think i get it now.. taking the intersection effectively starts with $P_v = V$ and removes vertices such that $P_v$ is still pred-closed and $v \in P_v$, until it cannot remove any more?

Answer (score 1):

$$P = \{v\} \cup \{ p : \exists n \in \Bbb N: \exists v_1, v_2,\ldots v_n \in V: v_1=p, v_n=v \land \forall i \le n-1: (v_i, v_{i+1}) \in E \}$$
 is one way to put it.

Comment: Thanks, just before I accept this as an answer, is this just a solution for vertices lying on a single path from $v$ to $v_n$ in a DAG? or does it also account for circumstances where $(v_2,v_1),(v_5,v_1) \in E$ and so $\{v_1,v_2,v_5\} \subseteq P_v$?

Comment: ah okay, i was also wondering where the $p$ went in the original answer as well..

Comment: @guskenny83 Yes, I made the definition more formal. Maybe add $\cup \{v\}$ for the case the $v$ is a starting vertex without predecessors as well.